# Laravel get specific relation data

Tags: laravel

Assuming I have a table & model named `UserActivity`.

Each row has the following fields: `id`, `user_id`.

When I query UserActivity with his `user` relation, I get all of the `user` information: his ID, email, and some other fields I don't need. All I need from this relation, is the username field.

How I can get only 3-4 specific fields from a relation assuming my current query to get all of them is:

```
return UserActivity::with('user')
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->take(5)->get();
```

The relation is **BelongsTo**.

Comment: Do you want only that user information in all queries involving UserActivity and User, or only in this specific query?

Comment: all queries involving UserActivity can be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will only return the columns 'col1', 'col2', etc from the relation.

```
return UserActivity::with(['user' => function($q) { 
                                       $q->select('id','col1', 'col2', ...); 
                                     }])
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->take(5)->get();
```

If you want to make sure that those columns are the only columns loaded on *all* queries where the user object is loaded from UserActivity, you can modify the relation as  such,

```
function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(...)->select(['col1, 'col2', ...]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great - just for making it clear: add to your answer that the user `ID` column must included in the `$q->select` query, without it `user` will always be `null`.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! The join fails when the id isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

```
return UserActivity::with(['user' => function ($query) {$query->select('name', 'email')}])
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->take(5)->get();
```